# .net MVC 4 return a pdf to browser

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, pdf

View

`@Html.ActionLink("Förköpsinformation", "GetForkopsInfo", "RaknaTeckna", null, new { target = "_blank" })`

The GetForkopsInfo() does the actionlink action, `tm.PreSalesDocument` is the pdf object in bytes

```
  [HttpPost]
   public ActionResult GetForkopsInfo()
    {

            tm = (TecknaMotor)Session["WinsureTecknaMotor"];
            tm.GetPreSalesDocument();


                Response.Clear();
                Response.ClearContent();
                Response.ClearHeaders();
                Response.ContentType = "Application/pdf";
                Response.AddHeader("content-length", tm.PreSalesDocument.Length.ToString());
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename = förköpsinfo.pdf");
                Response.BinaryWrite(tm.PreSalesDocument);
                return File(tm.PreSalesDocument, "Application/pdf", "förköpsinfo.pdf");

    }`
```

I want the controller to return the pdf to web browser and open a new tab.
But it's not working at all, im not even sure it is correct to use actionlink? Don't know how to do it exactly...

Comment: Are you wanting to use an HttpPost to get this file? what happens if you create a request through fiddler to test? What is your HTTP Response code? The ActionLink wont work if your type is of HttpPost which it is... You'll need some javascript to make that work. I recommend making this an HttpGet request.

Comment: Try returning a `FileContentResult` instead.

Comment: "But it's not working at all" - what does that mean? Nothing downloaded at all? what does the browser do? what does fiddler show?

Comment: @Tim it does open a new tab page, but it does not go into the ActionResult

Comment: @nilhulus read my comment..Especially the end.

Comment: @CaptainAnon what does the javascript do? I still need controller to get the pdf byte from the system.

Comment: @nihulus Try changing to an httpGet request. Thats what im saying. I meant if you want to use POST. You will need javascript.

Comment: @CaptainAnon Okay, it does working downloading but i want it to display in a new tab in browser

Answer (score 1):

Your attemtping to access an HttpPost ActionResult with an Actionlink which wont work out of the box. I reccomend you change the request to HTTPGet and have a look at HttpResponse.TransmitFile

```
Response.ContentType = "Application/pdf";
Response.TransmitFile(pathtofile);
```

And return that Response instead of the File Obj.

Alternatively, you can change to an HTTPGet and im fairly sure change your browser to open the PDF In a browser window.

Comment: Yes, I changed to httpget, Response.TransmitFile is not really needed here, all i did now is remove file name in the return parameters. `return File(tm.PreSalesDocument, "Application/pdf");` now it open in a new tab.